# How does the Chrome DevTools Protocol sort cookies?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium

When I do `Network.getCookies` or `Network.getAllCookies`, how does Chrome sort the returned list of cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome sorts the cookies first by path length (longest first), then by creation date (descending).

Source (Chromium source code): https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/network/public/mojom/cookie_manager.mojom?l=216-217&rcl=97f8d3cc1b46e4fe14b28f40ddabf273c2c8d005